# I am not able to link the libraries of opencv to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, opencv, libraries

I downloaded opencv as specified by http://miloq.blogspot.in/2012/12/install-opencv-ubuntu-linux.html

I downloaded eclipse and linked the libraries by following this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jSPoBgQPMI

But I am getting errors that show that the libraries have not been properly linked

Comment: can you paste the exact errors..

Answer (score 1):

To install opencv I used the following link which seemed to install everything I needed:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV

I followed the following guide and it got everything working for me without many hassles:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html

Note that I have never done any library linking before and it seemed OK. Unfortunately I don't know what language you're using so the process might be a little different for you (if it's not C/C++).

I hope this helps!